# Why does this bed work for me but not for someone else?

Tags: xbox-360, terraria-console

[image]

This spawn works for me perfectly fine, but not my partner in multiplayer on Xbox 360.  She tried both beds and they didn't work for her.

Answer (score -2):

Your in hell right? I'm sure you can't sleep in hell (not sure though) but I think that's why

Comment: And there's some host glitches where they can do stuff but others cant

Comment: Obviously it works for him, so this answer is very incorrect.